# Multiple Layer Show/Hide

Tags: javascript, css, html

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function setVisibility(id) {
  if(document.getElementById('bt1').value=='Hide Layer'){
    document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Show Layer';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Hide Layer';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
  }
}
```

```
<h4 id='bt1'  style="cursor: hand;" value='Show Layer' onclick="setVisibility('sub1');" >menu1</h4>
<span class="detail" id="sub1">menu1_contents</span>

<h4 id='bt1'  style="cursor: hand;" value='Show Layer' onclick="setVisibility('sub2');" >menu2</h4>
<span class="detail" id="sub2">menu2_contents</span>

<h4 id='bt1'  style="cursor: hand;" value='Show Layer' onclick="setVisibility('sub3');" >menu3</h4>
<span class="detail" id="sub1">menu3_contents</span>
```

One click -> Show Layer
Second Click -> Hide Layer

It's no problem while show/hide same menu.  But when i click "menu2", still remained "menu1_contents" on the background. And it's over wrapped when i click next menu.

How can i automatically hide "menu1"'s contents, when click "menu2".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would do it in jquery :

```
function setVisibility(id) {
  if($('#bt1').val()=='Hide Layer'){
     $('#bt1').val('Show Layer');
     $('#' + id).hide().removeClass("showing");
  }
  else{
    $('#bt1').val('Hide Layer');
    $('.showing').removeClass("showing");
    $('#' + id).show().addClass("showing");
    $('span:not(.showing)').hide();
  }
}
```

Oh and Add the jquery library, Really important

And if you really want to use javascript the idea that i've got is used if to hide each other span that are not the one that you're displaying right now (little crappy)

Comment: It works fine thanks. But still remains menu1's contents while swithcing to menu2. So menu1's contents and menu2's contents overwrapped.